# WebView - Window Leak

Tags: android, html, video, android-webview

I have read almost tens of questions on this on StackOverflow, but couldn't get any reliable solution.

I have an activity in which I am displaying videos from server. The videos are HTML5 and hence, i am using a HTML5WebView(just some methods overriden to support playing HTML5 videos, actually taken from a library somwhere on internet).

The videos are playing fine on Nexus5 with 4.4.2, but when playing on 2.3.6 and 2.3.5, there is a memory leak and the application crashes. I am not sure how to get around this, so if someone can help, it would be great.

I also read that this might be a bug, in lower versions, but if there is a workaround please do suggest that.

Here is my code...

custom_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_custom_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

WebViewActivity.java

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    HTML5WebView mWebView;
    public String url = "http://m.oxblue.com";
    public String fileName = "OxBlue-Photo.png";

    ProgressDialog pd;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "***** WebViewActivity - onCreate *****");

        mWebView = new HTML5WebView(this);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        } else {

            if (Const.DEBUGGING)
                Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "GLobal URL = " + url);

            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                    if (Const.DEBUGGING)
                        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "URL = " + url);

                    view.loadUrl(url);

                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                        Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                    pd = new ProgressDialog(WebViewActivity.this);
                    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
                    pd.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    pd.dismiss();
                }

            });
            mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                        long contentLength) {

                    Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Dowloading...");
                    Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "URL = " + url);

                    DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile(
                            WebViewActivity.this);
                    downloadFile.execute(url);

                }
            });

            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        }

        setContentView(mWebView.getLayout());

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "***** WebViewActivity - onStop *****");

        if (mWebView != null)
            mWebView.stopLoading();
        this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "***** WebViewActivity - onDestroy *****");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "***** WebViewActivity - onPause *****");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "***** WebViewActivity - onKeyDown *****");

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            this.finish();

            if (mWebView.inCustomView()) {
                mWebView.hideCustomView();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    //AsyncTask to download file... not related to the problem.. so removed
    }

}
```

HTML5WebView.java

```
public class HTML5WebView extends WebView {

    Activity a;

    private MyWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;
    private View mCustomView;
    private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;

    private FrameLayout mContentView;
    private FrameLayout mBrowserFrameLayout;
    private FrameLayout mLayout;

    static final String LOGTAG = "HTML5WebView";

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private void init(Context context) {
        Context mContext;

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "***** HTML5WebView - init *****");

        mContext = context;
        a = (Activity) mContext;

        mLayout = new FrameLayout(context);

        mBrowserFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(a).inflate(
                R.layout.custom_screen, null);
        mContentView = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_custom_content);

        mLayout.addView(mBrowserFrameLayout, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);

        WebSettings s = getSettings();
        s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        s.setSupportZoom(true);
        s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        s.setSaveFormData(true);
        s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
        setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mContentView.addView(this);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG,
                    "***** HTML5WebView - Single Parameter Constructor *****");

        init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG,
                    "***** HTML5WebView - 2 Parameter Constructor *****");

        init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG,
                    "***** HTML5WebView - 3 Parameter Constructor *****");

        init(context);
    }

    private boolean is_gone = false;

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
            Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "***** HTML5WebView - onFocusChanged *****");

        if (!focused) {
            try {
                WebView.class.getMethod("onPause").invoke(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            this.pauseTimers();
            this.is_gone = true;
        } else {
            try {
                WebView.class.getMethod("onResume").invoke(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            this.resumeTimers();
            this.is_gone = false;
        }

    }

    public void onWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {
        super.onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "***** HTML5WebView - onWindowVisibility *****");

        if (visibility == View.GONE) {
            try {
                WebView.class.getMethod("onPause").invoke(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            this.pauseTimers();
            this.is_gone = true;
        } else if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            try {
                WebView.class.getMethod("onResume").invoke(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            this.resumeTimers();
            this.is_gone = false;
        }
    }

    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG,
                    "***** HTML5WebView - onDetachedFromWindow *****");

        mContentView.removeAllViews();
        mBrowserFrameLayout.removeAllViews();
        mLayout.removeAllViews();

        if (this.is_gone) {
            try {
                this.destroy();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG,
                    "***** HTML5WebView - onDetachedFromWindow - Ending *****");

    }

    public FrameLayout getLayout() {

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "***** HTML5WebView - getLayout Method *****");

        return mLayout;
    }

    public boolean inCustomView() {

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "***** HTML5WebView - inCustomView Method *****");

        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    public void hideCustomView() {

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "***** HTML5WebView - hideCustomView *****");

        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (Const.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "***** HTML5WebView - onKeyDown *****");

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if ((mCustomView == null) && canGoBack()) {
                goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        private View mVideoProgressView;

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view,
                WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {

            if (Const.DEBUGGING)
                Log.d(Const.DEBUG,
                        "***** HTML5WebView - MyWebChromeClient - onShowCustomView *****");

            HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }

            mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
            mCustomView = view;
            mCustomViewCallback = callback;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {

            if (Const.DEBUGGING)
                Log.d(Const.DEBUG,
                        "***** HTML5WebView - MyWebChromeClient - onHideCustomView *****");

            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;

            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (mCustomViewCallback != null)
                mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

            mBrowserFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            a.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {

            if (Const.DEBUGGING)
                Log.d(Const.DEBUG,
                        "***** HTML5WebView - MyWebChromeClient - getVideoLoadingProgressView *****");

            if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(a);
                mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.video_loading_progress, null);
            }

            return mVideoProgressView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {

            if (Const.DEBUGGING)
                Log.d(Const.DEBUG,
                        "***** HTML5WebView - MyWebChromeClient - onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt *****");

            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    }

    static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

Logcat trace...

```
03-26 13:28:14.862: D/OxBlue(16557): ***** WebViewActivity - onPause *****
03-26 13:28:15.073: D/OxBlue(16557): ***** HTML5WebView - onWindowVisibility *****
03-26 13:28:15.133: D/OxBlue(16557): ***** WebViewActivity - onStop *****
03-26 13:28:15.133: D/webkit-timers(16557): [JWebCoreJavaBridge::pause] >> do pause
03-26 13:28:15.143: D/OxBlue(16557): ***** WebViewActivity - onDestroy *****
03-26 13:28:15.163: D/OxBlue(16557): ***** HTML5WebView - onDetachedFromWindow *****
03-26 13:28:15.163: D/OxBlue(16557): ***** HTML5WebView - onFocusChanged *****
03-26 13:28:15.163: D/OxBlue(16557): ***** HTML5WebView - onDetachedFromWindow *****
03-26 13:28:15.163: D/webviewglue(16557): nativeDestroy view: 0x2f0b68
03-26 13:28:15.163: D/OxBlue(16557): ***** HTML5WebView - onDetachedFromWindow - Ending *****
03-26 13:28:15.163: D/OxBlue(16557): ***** HTML5WebView - onDetachedFromWindow - Ending *****
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557): Activity com.xx.xxx.webview.WebViewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405da260 that was originally added here
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.xx.xxx.webview.WebViewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405da260 that was originally added here
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:277)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:433)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:265)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at android.widget.VideoView$4.onError(VideoView.java:386)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1476)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-26 13:28:15.183: E/WindowManager(16557):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 13:28:15.373: W/dalvikvm(16557): JNI: DeleteGlobalRef(0xde5deb2f) failed to find entry (valid=0)
03-26 13:28:15.373: W/dalvikvm(16557): JNI: DeleteGlobalRef(0xde5deb0f) failed to find entry (valid=0)
```

I have tried `removeAllViews()` in `onDetachedFromWindow()` inside HTML5WebView, but nothing changed.

Comment: This is not a memory leak.It's a window leak as specified in error "android.view.WindowLeaked".

Comment: ok.. will change the question title.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's leaking an AlertDialog that it tried to show due to encountering  an error loading the video

```
at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
at android.widget.VideoView$4.onError(VideoView.java:386)
```

Do you have access to the VideoView from your code? If so, you could try to use setOnErrorListener[1] to run an empty callback on error. I think it's the default behaviour that is trying to pop up the dialog.

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnErrorListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener)

Comment: What if I don't have the access for VideoView from the code? Is there any way I can get the access? I am really not sure, on how to get the access.

Comment: Did you see an alert dialog show in your app with a video error?

Comment: No.. I don't see any alert dialog in the app.

Comment: It looks like this leak is being logged when you try to close your app. Does it always occur, or only sometimes?

Comment: I am not trying to close the app. I am trying to play a video from inside the webview and it crashes. Yes, everytime i play the video it crashes. This is happening on 2.3.6 and 2.3.5 and not on 4.4.2

Comment: ok, the logcat you posted is going through onPause on WebViewActivity and several other methods that look related to your app tearing down (onStop, destroy, etc) which should only be called when your app is going to the background or closing (e.g. by pressing the back key). Are you calling this onPause or teardown code manually somewhere? It seems wrong if this is being called during the normal flow of your app.

Comment: I am not calling these anywhere else manually. Will go through it again and see.. I think the reason these methods are called is, Android is trying to open MediaPlayer to open the video and hence the activity is going to background

Comment: you can add Log.v("tag", "", new Throwable()) to WebViewActivity.onPause to see the stack of where it's coming from.